# Different frame heights on iOS 7 and iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8

So basically I am trying to dynamically change the height of a view based on three different labels inside of it. I use `_labelName_.frame.size.height` to get the height for all three. This works great in iOS 8, however in iOS 7 one returns 17 (should be 33), the other two both return 0, and they should be 22.5 and 16.5.

I'm at a loss as to why iOS 7 and iOS 8 are returning different frame heights, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Did a little debugging. Turns out, the frame heights *are* 0 in iOS 7, but not in iOS 8. It seems that layoutSubviews is working differently on iOS 7 than it is on iOS 8. Any reason that layoutSubviews would lay out the subviews differently between the two versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `[_labelName_ sizeToFit]` after setting the text and before accessing the frame

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks for the help! I was pulling my hair out at this one!